# How to translate an equation with exponents and sin function to C?

Tags: c, function, trigonometry, exp

How could I write it in C language? I tried many things, but it seems that I cannot understand the exp and sin functions.

[image]

Comment: Is there any more context to this function? It looks suspiciously like it is designed to force (severe) loss of accuracy, very roughly for |x| < 2, as there is cancellation of the constant, linear, quadratic, and cubic terms in the series expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct implementation could be:

```
double y = exp(pow(sin(x),3)) + pow(x,6) - 2*pow(x,4) - pow(x,3) - 1.0;
```